# Entity tracking in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I started reading more about EF. I believed that entities are tracked as long as the context is in scope. But when I try the code below, I get different results. The context has gone out of scope but the entity state still get changed from Unchanged to Modified. Did I misunderstood what I read? Can someone please explain.

```
Destination canyon;
DbEntityEntry<Destination> entry;

using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
{
    canyon = (from d in context.Destinations.Include(d => d.Lodgings)
                    where d.Name == "Grand Canyon"
                    select d).Single();
    entry = context.Entry<Destination>(canyon);
}

//Context gone out of scope
Console.WriteLine(entry.State); //Unchanged
canyon.TravelWarnings = "Carry enough water!";
Console.WriteLine(entry.State); //Modified
```

Comment: entity framework version?

Comment: Entity Framework Version 4.3.0

Comment: i believe that this issue is resolved in the newer versions of entity framework. think this is resolved in version 5+. is it essential that you stay on version 4.3?

Comment: @P6345uk, I downloaded some sample code that used version 4.3. I'm still reading EF!!!

Comment: I would update this to version 6.1.3 as the newer version resolves a few older issues.

Comment: if you are in visual studio you can do this via package manager
Update-Package EntityFramework

Comment: @P6345uk I upgraded to 6.1.3 and it behaves as expected. Thank you.